# Checkbox with three states

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm trying to do a checkbox with three states. For this I made a method that when clicking it navigates between states. The problem is that this method is only called after the HTML change. So it goes into my method after changing the state of the HTML making the navigation of the checkbox is wrong.

How could I make it call my method before changing it in HTML?

Navigation between states:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8cuA.jpg

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="switch switch-group" [ngClass]="getClasses()"  appAttribute [states]="states" [attr.disabled]="(disabled == 'disabled') ? 'disabled' : null" >
  <input #inputSwitch type="checkbox" appAttribute [states]="states" class="switch-checkbox" (click)="changeState()">
  <label class="switch-label">Example</label>
</div>
```

**My `component.ts`:**

```
  @ViewChild('inputSwitch') inputSwitch: ElementRef;

  changeState() {
    // Work
    if(this.states == 2) {    
      this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked == true ? false : true;
      console.log(this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked);      
    } 
    // Not work
    else if (this.states == 3) {
      switch(this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked)
      {
        case false:
          if(!this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.indeterminate) {
            this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked = true;
            break;
          } 
          else {
            this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked = false;            
            break;
          }
        case true:
          this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.indeterminate = true;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Would it not be simpler to skip the checkbox and just create a control that toggles between 3 different states on a click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hagner, the solution was to create a control that toggles between 3 different states on a click event.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="switch switch-group" [ngClass]="getClasses()"  appAttribute [states]="states" (click)="changeState()" [attr.disabled]="(disabled == 'disabled') ? 'disabled' : null" >
  <input #inputSwitch type="checkbox" appAttribute [states]="states" class="switch-checkbox">
  <span class="switch-warper">
  </span>
  <label class="switch-label">Example</label>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
  changeState() {
    if(this.states == 2) {    
      if(this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked) {
        this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked = false;
      } else {
        this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked = true;
      }
    } 
    else if (this.states == 3) {

      switch(this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked)
      {
        case false:
          if(!this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.indeterminate) {
            this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked = true;
            break;
          } 
          else if(this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.indeterminate) {
            this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked = false;   
            this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.indeterminate = false;
            break;
          }
        case true:
          this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.checked = false;                    
          this.inputSwitch.nativeElement.indeterminate = true;
          break;
      }

    }

  }
```

**SASS:**

```
input[type=checkbox].switch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
```